# Не работает свойство font-weight в CSS

Tags: css, html5

хотел сделать текст “жирным”, но когда я меняю значение свойства `font-weight`, ничего не происходит - текст остаётся таким, как есть (прикладываю фотографии с разными значениями - 56 строка)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div,
p,
nav,
input,
button,
form,
span,
a,
ul,
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}


/*______________________________*/

.title-2 {
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 0.016px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">

    <section class="DoYouKnow">
      <h2 class="title-2">do you know we can provide for you ?</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так может его нет такой жирности?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте правильность подключения шрифта, а именно все необходимые начертания!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div,
p,
nav,
input,
button,
form,
span,
a,
ul,
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}


/*______________________________*/

.title-2 {
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 0.016px;
  line-height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">

    <section class="DoYouKnow">
      <h2 class="title-2">do you know we can provide for you ?</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Нет, шрифт подключен правильно

Comment: @АртёмКузьминых, откройте файл https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap там же только начертание для 400 (normal)